# "github.com/gen2brain/go-fitz" giving trouble while building my go micro-service code for for linux - amd64 from my mac arm64

Tags: linux, macos, go, cross-compiling, mupdf

**I'm trying to build my go microservice in mac. My target system is linux-amd64.**

Following is my build command.
env CGO_ENABLED=1 GOOS=linux GOARCH=amd64 go build -o  main

**While doing the build, I'm getting an issue with  "github.com/gen2brain/go-fitz" package.**

It has a binary dependency on mupdf. It works fine while building from mac for mac, and linux for linux. But the cross-platform compilation failing. Is there a way to do the build for GOOS=linux GOARCH=amd64 from mac.

**Following is the error message I'm getting.**

> github.com/gen2brain/go-fitz ld: warning: ignoring file
> /Users/admin/go/pkg/mod/github.com/gen2brain/go-fitz@v0.0.0-20180416170014-297d6b608808/libs/libmupdfthird_linux_amd64.a,
> building for macOS-x86_64 but attempting to link with file built for
> unknown-unsupported file format ( 0x21 0x3C 0x61 0x72 0x63 0x68 0x3E
> 0x0A 0x2F 0x20 0x20 0x20 0x20 0x20 0x20 0x20 ) ld: warning: ignoring
> file
> /Users/admin/go/pkg/mod/github.com/gen2brain/go-fitz@v0.0.0-20180416170014-297d6b608808/libs/libmupdf_linux_amd64.a,
> building for macOS-x86_64 but attempting to link with file built for
> unknown-unsupported file format ( 0x21 0x3C 0x61 0x72 0x63 0x68 0x3E
> 0x0A 0x2F 0x20 0x20 0x20 0x20 0x20 0x20 0x20 ) Undefined symbols for
> architecture x86_64:
> Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
> "_fz_bound_page", referenced from:
> __cgo_3af09a676200_Cfunc_fz_bound_page in _x002.o
> (maybe you meant: __cgo_3af09a676200_Cfunc_fz_bound_page)   "_fz_clear_pixmap_with_value", referenced from:
> __cgo_3af09a676200_Cfunc_fz_clear_pixmap_with_value in _x002.o
> (maybe you meant: __cgo_3af09a676200_Cfunc_fz_clear_pixmap_with_value)   "_fz_close_device", referenced from:
> __cgo_3af09a676200_Cfunc_fz_close_device in _x002.o
> (maybe you meant: __cgo_3af09a676200_Cfunc_fz_close_device)   "_fz_count_pages", referenced from:
> __cgo_3af09a676200_Cfunc_fz_count_pages in _x002.o
> (maybe you meant: __cgo_3af09a676200_Cfunc_fz_count_pages)   "_fz_device_rgb", referenced from:
> __cgo_3af09a676200_Cfunc_fz_device_rgb in _x002.o
> (maybe you meant: __cgo_3af09a676200_Cfunc_fz_device_rgb)   "_fz_drop_buffer", referenced from:
> __cgo_3af09a676200_Cfunc_fz_drop_buffer in _x002.o
> (maybe you meant: __cgo_3af09a676200_Cfunc_fz_drop_buffer)   "_fz_drop_context", referenced from:
> __cgo_3af09a676200_Cfunc_fz_drop_context in _x002.o
> (maybe you meant: __cgo_3af09a676200_Cfunc_fz_drop_context)   "_fz_drop_device", referenced from:
> __cgo_3af09a676200_Cfunc_fz_drop_device in _x002.o
> (maybe you meant: __cgo_3af09a676200_Cfunc_fz_drop_device)   "_fz_drop_document", referenced from:
> __cgo_3af09a676200_Cfunc_fz_drop_document in _x002.o
> (maybe you meant: __cgo_3af09a676200_Cfunc_fz_drop_document)   "_fz_drop_output", referenced from:
> __cgo_3af09a676200_Cfunc_fz_drop_output in _x002.o
> (maybe you meant: __cgo_3af09a676200_Cfunc_fz_drop_output)   "_fz_drop_page", referenced from:
> __cgo_3af09a676200_Cfunc_fz_drop_page in _x002.o
> (maybe you meant: __cgo_3af09a676200_Cfunc_fz_drop_page)   "_fz_drop_pixmap", referenced from:
> __cgo_3af09a676200_Cfunc_fz_drop_pixmap in _x002.o
> (maybe you meant: __cgo_3af09a676200_Cfunc_fz_drop_pixmap)   "_fz_drop_stext_page", referenced from:
> __cgo_3af09a676200_Cfunc_fz_drop_stext_page in _x002.o
> (maybe you meant: __cgo_3af09a676200_Cfunc_fz_drop_stext_page)   "_fz_identity", referenced from:
> __cgohack_fz_identity in _cgo_main.o
> (maybe you meant: __cgohack_fz_identity)   "_fz_load_page", referenced from:
> __cgo_3af09a676200_Cfunc_fz_load_page in _x002.o
> (maybe you meant: __cgo_3af09a676200_Cfunc_fz_load_page)   "_fz_needs_password", referenced from:
> __cgo_3af09a676200_Cfunc_fz_needs_password in _x002.o
> (maybe you meant: __cgo_3af09a676200_Cfunc_fz_needs_password)   "_fz_new_buffer", referenced from:
> __cgo_3af09a676200_Cfunc_fz_new_buffer in _x002.o
> (maybe you meant: __cgo_3af09a676200_Cfunc_fz_new_buffer_from_stext_page, __cgo_3af09a676200_Cfunc_fz_new_buffer )   "_fz_new_buffer_from_stext_page", referenced from:
> __cgo_3af09a676200_Cfunc_fz_new_buffer_from_stext_page in _x002.o
> (maybe you meant: __cgo_3af09a676200_Cfunc_fz_new_buffer_from_stext_page)   "_fz_new_context_imp", referenced from:
> __cgo_3af09a676200_Cfunc_fz_new_context_imp in _x002.o
> (maybe you meant: __cgo_3af09a676200_Cfunc_fz_new_context_imp)   "_fz_new_draw_device", referenced from:
> __cgo_3af09a676200_Cfunc_fz_new_draw_device in _x002.o
> (maybe you meant: __cgo_3af09a676200_Cfunc_fz_new_draw_device)   "_fz_new_output_with_buffer", referenced from:
> __cgo_3af09a676200_Cfunc_fz_new_output_with_buffer in _x002.o
> (maybe you meant: __cgo_3af09a676200_Cfunc_fz_new_output_with_buffer)   "_fz_new_pixmap_with_bbox", referenced from:
> __cgo_3af09a676200_Cfunc_fz_new_pixmap_with_bbox in _x002.o
> (maybe you meant: __cgo_3af09a676200_Cfunc_fz_new_pixmap_with_bbox)   "_fz_new_stext_device", referenced from:
> __cgo_3af09a676200_Cfunc_fz_new_stext_device in _x002.o
> (maybe you meant: __cgo_3af09a676200_Cfunc_fz_new_stext_device)   "_fz_new_stext_page", referenced from:
> __cgo_3af09a676200_Cfunc_fz_new_stext_page in _x002.o
> (maybe you meant: __cgo_3af09a676200_Cfunc_fz_new_stext_page)   "_fz_new_svg_device", referenced from:
> __cgo_3af09a676200_Cfunc_fz_new_svg_device in _x002.o
> (maybe you meant: __cgo_3af09a676200_Cfunc_fz_new_svg_device)   "_fz_open_document", referenced from:
> __cgo_3af09a676200_Cfunc_fz_open_document in _x002.o
> (maybe you meant: __cgo_3af09a676200_Cfunc_fz_open_document_with_stream, __cgo_3af09a676200_Cfunc_fz_open_document )   "_fz_open_document_with_stream", referenced from:
> __cgo_3af09a676200_Cfunc_fz_open_document_with_stream in _x002.o
> (maybe you meant: __cgo_3af09a676200_Cfunc_fz_open_document_with_stream)   "_fz_open_memory", referenced from:
> __cgo_3af09a676200_Cfunc_fz_open_memory in _x002.o
> (maybe you meant: __cgo_3af09a676200_Cfunc_fz_open_memory)   "_fz_pixmap_samples", referenced from:
> __cgo_3af09a676200_Cfunc_fz_pixmap_samples in _x002.o
> (maybe you meant: __cgo_3af09a676200_Cfunc_fz_pixmap_samples)   "_fz_print_stext_header_as_html", referenced from:
> __cgo_3af09a676200_Cfunc_fz_print_stext_header_as_html in _x002.o
> (maybe you meant: __cgo_3af09a676200_Cfunc_fz_print_stext_header_as_html)   "_fz_print_stext_page_as_html", referenced from:
> __cgo_3af09a676200_Cfunc_fz_print_stext_page_as_html in _x002.o
> (maybe you meant: __cgo_3af09a676200_Cfunc_fz_print_stext_page_as_html)   "_fz_print_stext_page_as_text", referenced from:
> __cgo_3af09a676200_Cfunc_fz_print_stext_page_as_text in _x002.o
> (maybe you meant: __cgo_3af09a676200_Cfunc_fz_print_stext_page_as_text)   "_fz_print_stext_trailer_as_html", referenced from:
> __cgo_3af09a676200_Cfunc_fz_print_stext_trailer_as_html in _x002.o
> (maybe you meant: __cgo_3af09a676200_Cfunc_fz_print_stext_trailer_as_html)   "_fz_register_document_handlers", referenced from:
> __cgo_3af09a676200_Cfunc_fz_register_document_handlers in _x002.o
> (maybe you meant: __cgo_3af09a676200_Cfunc_fz_register_document_handlers)   "_fz_round_rect", referenced from:
> __cgo_3af09a676200_Cfunc_fz_round_rect in _x002.o
> (maybe you meant: __cgo_3af09a676200_Cfunc_fz_round_rect)   "_fz_run_page", referenced from:
> __cgo_3af09a676200_Cfunc_fz_run_page in _x002.o
> (maybe you meant: __cgo_3af09a676200_Cfunc_fz_run_page)   "_fz_scale", referenced from:
> __cgo_3af09a676200_Cfunc_fz_scale in _x002.o
> (maybe you meant: __cgo_3af09a676200_Cfunc_fz_scale)   "_fz_string_from_buffer", referenced from:
> __cgo_3af09a676200_Cfunc_fz_string_from_buffer in _x002.o
> (maybe you meant: __cgo_3af09a676200_Cfunc_fz_string_from_buffer)   "_fz_transform_rect", referenced from:
> __cgo_3af09a676200_Cfunc_fz_transform_rect in _x002.o
> (maybe you meant: __cgo_3af09a676200_Cfunc_fz_transform_rect) ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64 clang: error: linker
> command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Please help me resolve this issue.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: https://github.com/gen2brain/go-fitz/issues/7 It looks like you can't _just_ cross-compile as it uses cgo, so you need a C compiler for the target system and CGO_ENABLED=1 set. Might be easier building it in the cloud on a the target architecture. Otherwise, there are some instructions to try in that thread.

Comment: Thanks for the help.

Comment: Found something here: https://subscription.packtpub.com/book/application_development/9781789138412/app02/app02lvl1sec98/cross-compiling-for-linux-with-cgo

Comment: But still, it is giving error,

Comment: The above packetpub link mentioned some toolchain for mac. But the build is giving errors, even after using it for CC and CXX. /usr/local/Cellar/musl-cross/0.9.9/libexec/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-musl/9.2.0/../../../../x86_64-linux-musl/bin/ld: /Users/asishtom/go/pkg/mod/github.com/gen2brain/go-fitz@v0.0.0-20180416170014-297d6b608808/libs/libmupdfthird_linux_amd64.a(one.o): in function `fmtdate':